# How to remove a COM+ application using WIX3.0?

Tags: wix, wix3, com+

I have scoured the internet, and not found anything about how to do this. Essentially, we are replacing an old VB6 COM+ application with a .NET one. We are using WIX to install our new .NET application. As part of this installation, we need to remove the old COM+ components.

I can see plenty of information on how to install COM+ applications using WIX, but how do I simply remove one? I have downloaded the source for wix and peeked at the comPlus library but can't see anything obvious.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything available today in the WiX toolset that will remove COM+ applications during install.